# The time "command" lets your profile runtime. Is there a command that lets you profile max and average memory consumption?

Tags: linux, bash

What tools can I use, besides continually checking "top" to profile a linux binary file.

Ubuntu shootouts seems to do this and it looks like their using custom written python scripts

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/

I was wondering if there's a more out of the box way of doing this

Comment: That's kind of opinion based question.

Comment: If someone had asked, how do I time program execution in a linux environment, people would answer use the "time" command. Why is it opinion based asking how to profile memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a command that lets you profile max and average memory
>   consumption?

Yes, use a standalone [time](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) tool instead of builtin bash `time`. To invoke it, you should specify its full path, usually `/usr/bin/time`. At least you can see `maximum resident set size` in it's output for maximum memory consumption. See sample output in this question [Shell execution: time vs. /usr/bin/time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19236448/72178), for example.